# Using Captcha NUsoap Web Services

Tags: php, nusoap

I am working on Web Services via NUsoap for the e-bank system the Web Services is login system and everything is fine but my probelm how to use Captcha?

how to intigrate Captcha to valid login inside my Web Services?? any solution for this?

[image]

NUsoap Web Services

Comment: captchas are normally for identifying that users are human and not bots. Web services are for system to system interaction. Why would you want a captcha in a web service??

Comment: I know what Captcha is, but the developer for e-bank have limittion to do captachs, and ask me to do captacha via web services?

Comment: seem odd, but i have to do it

Comment: I think if you do that, it will make it impossible for another program to talk to your service (which should be the intention of a webservice). I'm not even sure it's actually possible to do it, because captchas are displayed via a HTML GUI. Because a webservice is not designed for human interaction, it doesn't have a GUI and doesn't use HTML.